# Consolidate overlapping time periods stored as start and end time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sequence, gaps-and-islands

I have DB table with two columns of interest, the first is the start(or On) time, the second the end (or Off) time for numerous events within a given physical area.

The requirement is to identify the unique period of time during which a vehicle was within the area. So the start of the first event to the end of the last as a continuous period. The number of on or off event in the period is not needed for the resulting table.

There are millions of rows so a join may cause problems due to the size fo the resulting table. I'm not against it but...

Data :

```
id          timeOn                    timeOff
761058840   2018-01-02 07:54:28.000   2018-01-02 08:33:34.000
761058840   2018-01-02 07:54:28.000   2018-01-02 08:36:30.000
761058840   2018-01-02 08:33:45.000   2018-01-02 08:35:30.000
761058840   2018-01-02 13:11:18.000   2018-01-02 13:14:04.000
761058840   2018-01-02 13:11:18.000   2018-01-02 13:39:40.000
761058840   2018-01-02 13:22:11.000   2018-01-02 13:40:25.000
761058840   2018-01-02 15:56:18.000   2018-01-02 15:59:34.000
761058840   2018-01-02 15:56:18.000   2018-01-02 16:36:25.000
761058840   2018-01-02 16:01:34.000   2018-01-02 16:05:34.000
761058840   2018-01-02 16:33:19.000   2018-01-02 16:38:26.000
761058840   2018-01-02 21:20:25.000   2018-01-02 21:24:25.000
761058840   2018-01-02 22:20:36.000   2018-01-03 05:20:37.000
761058840   2018-01-02 22:20:36.000   2018-01-03 05:20:37.000
761058840   2018-01-03 08:31:29.000   2018-01-03 09:01:10.000
761058840   2018-01-03 08:31:59.000   2018-01-03 09:01:07.000
761058840   2018-01-03 09:01:57.000   2018-01-03 09:06:27.000
761058840   2018-01-03 14:07:27.000   2018-01-03 14:17:32.000
761058840   2018-01-03 14:09:28.000   2018-01-03 14:45:00.000
761058840   2018-01-03 14:19:32.000   2018-01-03 14:48:22.000
761058840   2018-01-03 17:30:38.000   2018-01-03 18:06:35.000
761058840   2018-01-03 17:33:54.000   2018-01-03 18:09:48.000
```

Consider the rows in this data, what I'm looking for is :

```
761058840   2018-01-02 07:54:28.000   2018-01-02 08:36:30.000
761058840   2018-01-02 13:11:18.000   2018-01-02 13:40:25.000
761058840   2018-01-02 15:56:18.000   2018-01-02 16:38:26.000
761058840   2018-01-02 21:20:25.000   2018-01-02 21:24:25.000
761058840   2018-01-02 22:20:36.000   2018-01-03 05:20:37.000
761058840   2018-01-03 08:31:59.000   2018-01-03 09:01:07.000
761058840   2018-01-03 09:01:57.000   2018-01-03 09:06:27.000
761058840   2018-01-03 14:07:27.000   2018-01-03 14:48:22.000
761058840   2018-01-03 17:30:38.000   2018-01-03 18:09:48.000
```

Other solutions are for dates, I have multiple events within an hour. other solutions are categorizing the events into periods (binning them by hours).

There doesn't seem to be any things for continuous times.

The DB is SQL Server so T-SQL or ANSI would be ideal but I'm prepared for a bit of translation.

(edit for clarification : I'm trying to combine the sequence of overlapping times from timeOn to timeOff into a single row for each continuous sequence)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you trying to select *particular* rows in the table?  Or are you trying to *combine* multiple rows into a single row?

Comment: It is better to write expected output from input.

Comment: Are you sure your expected output is based on your sample data? why is this row excluded `761058840 2018-01-02 08:33:45.000 2018-01-02 08:35:30.000`? Also, does the `Id` column refer to the "physical area"?

Comment: The Id column is a vehicle. The 'area'  is a diferent column not shown. I didn't want to complicate the detail of the data just explain the reasoning for the issue. The line you mention is within duration of the datetime pair in the line above it.

Comment: Don't you think the !Area" column is pertinent here? You first paragraph says "within a given physical area"

Comment: the vehicle (or where it is) isn't essential. The problem concerned the datetime pairs I could have left the id out it would not have changed the issue of finding the first and last of the overlapping times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem of **merging overlapping intervals**. The simplest solution is to order the data by start point and group rows, start new group each time you find a gap between max. end point over previous rows and start point of current row.

The following solution is based on this idea (I used `ROWS BETWEEN ...` instead of `LAG`):

```
WITH t_with_change AS (
    SELECT id, timeOn, timeOff, CASE WHEN MAX(timeOff) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY timeOn ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) >= timeOn THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM @t
), t_with_groups AS(
    SELECT id, timeOn, timeOff, SUM(chg) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY timeOn) AS grp
    FROM t_with_change
)
SELECT id, grp, MIN(timeOn) AS timeOn, MAX(timeOff) AS timeOff
FROM t_with_groups
GROUP BY id, grp
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9be3f243ac5f3d7f912d71a836b22ca)

Comment: Not only does this solve my problem it means I can eliminate two steps I used to get to the point where I asked the question. It seems that T-SQL has grown up a little since I last used it in anger with Sybase 11.9.2. Now I need to understand that second line...

Comment: PS: it is very easy to understand if you add `chg` column to `t_with_groups` and do a `SELECT * FROM t_with_groups`. The change flag is based on a simplification of `LAG()` function (`LAG` would have required an extra cte).